# Nutch additional fields for indexing in solr

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch 1.19 and solr 8.11.2. For additional field crawling like h1, h2 and h3 I added new fields in /plugins/indexer-solr/schema.xml:

```
            <field name="h1" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
        <field name="h2" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
        <field name="h3" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

        
    </fields>
    ...
    ...


<copyField source="h1" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="h2" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="h3" dest="text"/>
```

After starting the crawling process, nutch runs but with no effect to the solr database. Does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Is the "headings" plugin activated in the property [plugin.includes](https://nutch.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/apidocs/resources/nutch-default.xml#plugin.includes)?

Comment: No I didn't, this is what I entered as described in the documentation: `<name>index.parse.md</name>      
<value>metatag.description,metatag.keywords,metatag.h1,metatag.h2,metatag.h3</value>`

Comment: But how can I include h1 - h3 in plugin.includes, it isn't described?!

Comment: You need to activate the headings plugin by adding it to the property plugin.includes, eg. `<property><name>plugin.includes</name><value>protocol-okhttp|parse-html|headings</value></property>` (likely more plugins are activated in your configuration).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your quick response, I added "headings" in plugin.includes with no result. When I delete field and copyField, it begins again to index. Do I have to change more than nutch-site.xml and schema.xml?